# MySQL Loop using group by

Tags: php, mysql

Heres my table:

```
Table: category
----------------
id | category 
------------------
1  |  category1 
2  |  category2
3  |  category3
4  |  category4
5  |  category5
```

-

```
Table: news
------------------------------
id | title      | category_id
------------------------------
 1 | title 1    |      1
 2 | title 2    |      2
 3 | title 3    |      4 
 4 | title 4    |      5
 5 | title 5    |      3
 6 | title 6    |      3
 7 | title 7    |      2
 8 | title 8    |      5
 9 | title 9    |      1
 10| title 10   |      4
 11| title 11   |      1
 12| title 12   |      2
```

how to get **mysql result** like this:

(note: each category (1-5) assigned with one title only, then repeat again the cycle of category.)

I have tried using `group by order by.

```
Category 1     ===
   title 1


 Category 2
   title

 Category 3
    title 5


Category 4
     title 3

Category 5
     title 4

Category 1     ===
     title 9

Category 2
     title 

category 3
      title 6

 category 4
       title10

 category 5
       title 8

 category 1      ===
       title 11

  category 2
        title 12
```

Comment: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Comment: can you explain more on the pattern of your displayed result? Are you wanting to repeat Category 1-5, going through all of the titles?

Comment: @Sean: yes.. repeat category 1-5

Comment: Why are `Category 2` and `Category 3` indented an extra space the first time? Is that part of what you want?

Comment: Create a 2-dimensional array from the results, where the first dimension is the category, the 2nd dimension is an array of all the elements in the category. Then loop through the categories, shifting an item off the sub-array and printing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to build such format using PHP, alternatively, you could use a while loop to create it. Consider this example:

First off, you need to properly query those values together, you can use join

```
// SAMPLE => SELECT * FROM `category` 
//    LEFT JOIN `news` ON `news`.`category_id` = `category`.`id`
```

Sample Output: [**SQL HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0cb14/4)

Secondly, after getting the values, you need to order them, In this case, `(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`

Consider this example:

```
$results_from_db = array(
    array('id' => 1, 'category' => 'category1', 'title' => 'title 1', 'category_id' => 1),
    array('id' => 1, 'category' => 'category1', 'title' => 'title 9', 'category_id' => 1),
    array('id' => 1, 'category' => 'category1', 'title' => 'title 11', 'category_id' => 1),
    array('id' => 2, 'category' => 'category2', 'title' => 'title 2', 'category_id' => 2),
    array('id' => 2, 'category' => 'category2', 'title' => 'title 7', 'category_id' => 2),
    array('id' => 2, 'category' => 'category2', 'title' => 'title 12', 'category_id' => 2),
    array('id' => 3, 'category' => 'category3', 'title' => 'title 5', 'category_id' => 3),
    array('id' => 3, 'category' => 'category3', 'title' => 'title 6', 'category_id' => 3),
    array('id' => 4, 'category' => 'category4', 'title' => 'title 3', 'category_id' => 4),
    array('id' => 4, 'category' => 'category4', 'title' => 'title 10', 'category_id' => 4),
    array('id' => 5, 'category' => 'category5', 'title' => 'title 4', 'category_id' => 5),
    array('id' => 5, 'category' => 'category5', 'title' => 'title 8', 'category_id' => 5),
);


$ids = array();
foreach($results_from_db as $value) {$ids[] = $value['id'];}
$ids = array_values(array_unique($ids));
sort($ids);
$needle_key = 0;

// build the data (kinda like recursive searching)
$data = array();
while(true) {
    $current_value = array_shift($results_from_db);
    if($current_value['category_id'] == $ids[$needle_key]) {
        $data[] = $current_value;
        $needle_key++;
        if($needle_key > count($ids)-1) {
            $needle_key = 0; // resetter
        }
    } else {
        array_push($results_from_db, $current_value);
    }

    if(empty($results_from_db)) {
        break;
    }
}
?>

<!-- if you want to echo -- >
<?php foreach($data as $key => $value): ?>
    <?php echo '<strong>'.$value['category'].'</strong><br/>'; ?>
    <?php echo str_repeat('&nbsp;', 8) . $value['title'].'<br/><br/>'; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Should output something like this: [**Sample Fiddle**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/AY6uZ1)

```
category1
        title 1

category2
        title 2

category3
        title 5

category4
        title 3

category5
        title 4

category1
        title 9

category2
        title 7

category3
        title 6

category4
        title 10

category5
        title 8

category1
        title 11

category2
        title 12
```

Comment: The OP wanted Category1 to Category 5 with one assigned title only, then repeat again the cycle of category.